# Class Execution Erros when using type = module on JS

Tags: javascript, class, module, scope

I need to pass a variable from a class ( in one j.s file ) to another class ( another j.s file ) in order to make a function in the second j.s file thats need a variable from the first j.s file.

The way Im trying to do is by "module" ( import / export ) but when I write type = "module" on the "script link" my class I got a "reference error" that says my class is not defined!
Can someone help me out with this solution or another way to do it ?

I also tried in another way: created a custom-event in the first j.s file to pass the data to the another j.s file into a event-listener but Its been harder to face the scopes scenarios

console =
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: CreatingResult is not defined
at index.html:38:21
at index.html:45:5

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please [edit] your question to include the text.

Comment: "*The way Im trying to do is by "module" ( import / export ) but when I write type = "module" on the "script link" my class I got a "reference error" that says my class is not defined*" sounds like you've not actually added the import and/or export.

Comment: Variables declared in modules, whether exported or not, do not become global variables. If you want that then you have to explicitly make it global, e.g. `window.CreateMarquee = ...`

Comment: Felix Kling , where do I need to put "window.createMarquee" ? after the const keyword ?